# How to update tar file that has gzip compression

Tags: bash, compression, tar

I executed:

```
tar -Ppcfz backup.tar.gz on /location/
```

This will:
Create a new tar file for the /location/
Preserve paths,
Preserve permissions,
Compress using gzip

I need to later update this tar file with files from /location/ that have not been added or are new:

```
tar -Ppuf backup.tar.gz /location/
```

I get errors:

> tar: This does not look like a tar archive tar: Skipping to next
>   header tar: Archive contains obsolescent base-64 headers tar:
>   Unexpected EOF in archive tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now

Help please.

Comment: Should be `tar -Ppczf`. The `-f` has to be the option immediately before `backup.tar.gz`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try using the `-z` flag when updating as well, but my version of tar reports that it can't update compressed archives. So you need to `gunzip` the file, then update with `tar`, then `gzip`.